# Client Credentials for Cloud Foundry UAA Server

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

When using the command cf oauth-token the cli fetches an oauth token for us by contacting the UAA server.I wanted to know what client credentials does the cli use for this purpose? Is there any pre-canned credentials I can use to make request to /token endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the refresh token stored in $CF_HOME/.cf/config.json (which was retrieved from UAA previously when logging in) together with client id "cf" and client secret "".